# Bottom Safe Area color goes through the translucent keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uikeyboard

I currently have the bottom safe area's color set as blue by setting the view's background color as UIColor.blue

However, the problem is when the keyboard comes up as a first responder, I still get a slight tint of that blue coming through from that background. Is there a way to make this translucent keyboard not happen?

[image: Blue safe area color]

[image: blue shade in the keyboard]

Comment: I think it's not possible with current ios sdk, but you can try to move your below content up a bit when keyboard is showing, and provide a white background afterwise.

Comment: Coming with the new SwiftUI, introduced at WWDC 2021, you can use the `safeAreaInsets` modifier (Look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10021/) video from apple at around min. 9:30). Before that, you probably have to fiddle around, maybe with ZStacks that are under the visible part of the keyboard